# Please explain 要不了多久

Tags: grammar

Please help me explain how 要不了多久 is translated into "It won't be long"

Literal meaning would be "Could not demand how long?"
I am not sure how 多久 works in this context.

Comment: it will not demand 多久／much time, cf. 过不了多久...  it won't be long before.., 多久?  How long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion came from only thinking 多 as "how" as in:

- 多少? (how many?)
- 多快？(how fast?)
- 多久？ (how long?) * time

However, 多 can, and mostly means "many/much" as in:

- 多日 (many days)
- 多人 (many people)
- 多時 (much time)

In 過不了多久, you don't see a question mark, which mean it is not a question, and 多 here means " much" and 久 means " long time"

The structure of this phrase is: 
要不了(would not take) 多(much) 久(long time)

多 here function as "**very**"