# Why does the shopkeeper say 要不了 (yào bùliǎo) after the customer proposes a too-low price?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A Mandarin Corner [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXBzyL9dnTo&t=227s) shows a woman haggling over a scarf in Hong Kong.

[image]

A snippet from their dialogue:

> 这个六十块钱，可以吧？
> <sub>Zhège liùshí kuài qián, kěyǐ ba?</sub>
>
> 六十块，**要不了**。
> <sub>Liùshí kuài, **yào bùliǎo**.</sub>
>
> **要不了**啊？
> <sub>**Yào bùliǎo** a?</sub>
>
> 对啊。
> <sub>Duì a.</sub>
>
> 我觉得一百五也太贵了！算了，算了。那我们就再看一下吧。
> <sub>Wǒ juédé yībǎi wǔ yě tài guìle! Suànle, suànle. Nà wǒmen jiù zài kàn yīxià ba.</sub>

(She eventually gets the shopkeeper down to 65 yuan!  Impressive.)

I don't understand what 要不了 (yào bùliǎo) means here.  It turns up in various sentences in [Jukuu.com](http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E8%A6%81%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86) (e.g. 要不了多久 (yào bùliǎo duōjiǔ) seems to mean "it won't take much time", and this was raised in [another question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21891/please-explain-%E8%A6%81%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86%E5%A4%9A%E4%B9%85)) which doesn't seem relevant to the dialogue above.  [Youdao](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E8%A6%81%E4%B8%8D%E4%BA%86) gives "otherwise the", which doesn't make sense.

**Question**: What does 要不了 in the above dialogue mean?

Comment: "Youdao gives "otherwise the", which doesn't make sense." Yes, for "otherwise" it is "要不"

Comment: Nothing impressive about turning a $150 price into $65, specially for foreigners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'**要**不了' in this context simply means "can't **take**" (can't **accept**).

In English, it would be "I can't take $60 HKD (for this merchandise)"

The shopkeeper refused to take the $60 HKD in exchange of that particular merchandise

***要了***那六十块就要交出商品了 (if she **took** that $60 HKD, she would have to hand over the merchandise)

Answer (score 1):

**要不了** in the above dialogue means refuse.

**in more specific word**,shopkeeper will say:**六十块我都要不了（到 )货** （i cant stock this up in such low price,so it's less likely to sell you.）

sometime chinese use the wrong word in oral,so you need to catch the main point like **不**.
Try to understand them in a simple way because not everyone cant afford the fee of well-education.

Comment: If the shopkeeper wanted to reason with the customers that the wholesale price is more than $60, she would simply say 来价也不止六十块哦!

Answer (score 0):

Don't really like 要不了 in your example, better 卖不了。

1. I ask you to go and buy something for me.You are not sure of the price of the article. You ask me:

这个东西六十块钱够吗？

I know it won't cost that much, it is less than 60, I say:

要不了六十块。

2. You make an offer of a price to a shopkeeper

这个六十块钱，可以吧？Will you take 60 for this?
六十块卖不了。I won't sell it for 60.

Comment: Oh, maybe this is because it was filmed in Hong Kong.

Comment: @Pedroski 要不了六十块 and 六十块(我)要不了 are different

Comment: @Becky 李蓓 Yeah, many Hong Kong people's Mandarin is just so so